Complexity of gaussian superposition preparation in Regev's factorisation algorithm
I'm going through the Regev's factorisation algorithm, and I don't understand how, for the Gaussian state preparation, he achieves a complexity of $d(\log D+ \text{poly}(\log d))$.
He says:

"the $\text{poly}(\log d)$ term is for computing the rotation needed for each of
the $O(\log d)$ most significant qubits"

But by using the method described in the referred Grover-Rodolph's paper, as I understand it, you'd need to do $O(2^n)$ controlled rotation (by recursively doing it for each of the $2^n$ possible states spanned by the $n$ qubits).
So even by only considering the $\log(d)$ most significant qubits, I get $O(2^{\log(d)}) = O(d)$. Therefore, I have that we need $\text{poly}(d)$ gates for the controlled rotation and not $\text{poly}(\log(d))$.
I guess I'm missing some optimisation somewhere. Even by using the symmetry of Gaussian, we cannot improve the asymptotic complexity.
Can you please enlighten me?

In some cases, Gaussian states can be prepared efficiently. See here for details: https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.10918

I think you may have somehow misunderstood the paper. The authors start off with a given discretized distribution, and then augment it one qubit at a time. For each additional qubit, there is only a single controlled rotation (by an angle $\theta_i$ that is stored in a quantum register, to use the notation from the paper). So if the final distribution is over $N = 2^n$ states, then there are at most $n$ such controlled rotations.
To answer the comment: Note that the authors write that they compute $\theta_i \equiv \text{arccos} \sqrt{f(i)}$ (in superposition) and then rotate by $\theta_i$ to map $|0\rangle \rightarrow \cos \theta_i |0\rangle +  \sin \theta_i |1\rangle$ so as to partition the probability mass, see (5–6). (We have that $\cos^2 \theta_i + \sin^2 \theta_i = 1$.) There is only one angle $\theta_i$ (stored in a quantum register, in superposition) involved every time that we augment the distribution with an additional qubit.

But according to (this)[https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33722/how-does-the-induction-step-in-the-grover-rudolph-scheme-to-prepare-superpositio] answer , when he goes from 1 to 2 qubits, he uses 2 angles (chosen based on each of previous qubit state)

@L.DZ I added an answer above. I hope this clarifies the situation.
