# What's the circuit to create superpositions corresponding to efficiently integrable probability distributions?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, state-preparation

See article here: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0208112

There are two steps in this procedure that I am curious about. First off, they suppose one can construct a circuit which efficiently performs the computation

$$\sqrt{p_i^{(m)} } |i\rangle|0\cdots 0\rangle \rightarrow \sqrt{p_i^{(m)} } |i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle.$$
How would one implement such a circuit? My guess is that one implements it in a similar way that one would on a classical computer, but quantum parallelism allows for $\theta_i$ to be calculated for all bit-combinations simultaneously. However, I have no idea how one starts when designing such circuits. Is there any place I can learn this so I can implement this procedure for any function $f(i) = \theta_i$?

The next step of the procedure involves the evolution
$$\sqrt{p_i^{(m)} } |i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle|0\rangle \rightarrow \sqrt{p_i^{(m)} } |i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle(\cos\theta_i|0\rangle + \sin \theta_i|1\rangle). $$
This step is also completely unfamiliar to me. How does one perform a rotation on an ancilla qubit, where the rotation angle is given by the binary number represented by the state $|\theta_i\rangle$?

Any literature or answers getting me closer to learning this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please change the link to the abstract: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0208112 instead of the PDF.

Comment: does this help https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12104/11793

Comment: It does help, Condo. Thank you. I am however still confused regarding how one implements $U_p$. Is there any computer science litterature that can help me understand this?

Comment: Regarding the bounty: show the practical implementation of loading some log-concave distributions (eg gaussian) in some quantum circuit having a small number of qubits (eg 5)  is enough to win the bounty

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33722/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/33739/55